# iOS7: UISearchBar scope buttons misaligned

Tags: ios7, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Ok, I bumped into another iOS7 weirdness:

I am adding a `UISearchdisplayController` + `UISearchBar` with some scope buttons programmatically to a table view.

Now, if I select the search field, the scope buttons are too large. If I switch to landscape, things get even worse, the buttons are badly misaligned.

Here is my code (just a few lines added to the standard 'Master Detail Application"-template):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // ... 

    UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
    searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;
    searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = @[@"one", @"two"];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
    self.mySearchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];

    // ... add delegate, datasource, irrelevant for this example
}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]
[image]

Addition:
By the way, the misalignment also appears if I hook things up with IB instead. The button width is correct though.

Does anyone have an idea for a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Change the initializer you have used to instantiate the search bar with something like this UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];. Seems to be a problem related with the designated initializer for the search bar.